# Proof about non-compact sets and unbounded functions

Tags: calculus, general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-compact subset. Show that there exists a continuous unbounded function on $A$.

I have split this into two parts. Either:

$A$ is unbounded but closed,

or

$A$ is closed but unbounded (same argument as both closed and unbounded)

If $A$ is not bounded then we cannot contain it in a ball of radius $r < \infty$, so let $f(a) = a$ for $a \in A$ and clearly f is unbounded. (Actually, now that I think about this more, I do not think this argument will work if $A$ is both closed AND unbounded, but only just unbounded.)

I can't think of an unbounded but continuous function for A being bounded but not closed.

Comment: What does it mean that $A$ is not closed? What property do points in $\overline{A}\setminus A$ have?

Comment: Well, the definition my book uses for a closed set is that the complement is open. So that's all I have to work with right now. (I know of the limit points definition but I am not allowed to use that.)

Points in the set you described, when you take any ball around them, they have points both in $A$ and in $A^c$.

Comment: Well, you know that the complement of $A$ is not open. By definition that means there are points in the complement such that every ball around such a point intersects $A$. Have you an idea how to use that?

Comment: not immediately - just to be clear - can i think of a function being "bounded" the same way, that is, i can enclose the image in a ball?

Comment: Yes, a function is bounded if there is a $K < \infty$ with $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant K$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far perfect:

> - If $A$ is unbounded, then $f:=a\mapsto a$ is an unbounded continuous function $A\to\Bbb R^n$. 
>     If we'd prefer an $A\to\Bbb R$ function, we could take $f:=a\mapsto \|a\|\ $ (with any norm). 
>     It doesn't matter if $A$ was closed or not.
> - If $A$ is not closed, then its complement is not open, so it contains a point $x\notin A$ such that none of its neighborhoods are totally contained in complement of $A$. 
>     In other words, each neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$. 
>     Now define $\ f:= a\mapsto \displaystyle\frac1{\|a-x\|}\ $ and prove that it is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks! just to clarify, are we looking for a bound that is outside the bound of $A$ or a bound that is not finite?

Comment: I guess, it was meant that the function is real valued and it approaches $\infty$ while approaching the boundary.